# Node.Js and MongoDB linking issue

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm new to this and trying my hands on this weather app project using node.js and MongoDB, with OpenWeathermap API, among other things, however I run node server.js, I get the following error:

```
PS E:\Project\Weather_v1\server> node server.js
Server is running on port 5000
MongoDB connection error: MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:788
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED
::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:788:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:763:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 613426814,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:367:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:290:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
PS E:\Project\Weather_v1\server> node server.js
Server is running on port 5000
MongoDB connection error: MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:788
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED
::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:788:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:763:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 614273212,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:367:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\Project\Weather_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:290:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v18.17.0
```

Here's my code for server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; // You can choose any available port number

// Set up Express middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost/weather_app'; // Change 'weather_app' to your desired database name
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

// server.js (continued)
// Import weather controller
const weatherController = require('./controllers/weatherController');

// API routes
app.get('/api/weather', weatherController.getWeatherByCity);
```

The WeatherCard.js file:

```
// WeatherCard.js
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';

const WeatherCard = ({ weather }) => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{weather.name}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>{weather.weather[0].description}</Card.Text>
        <Card.Text>Temperature: {weather.main.temp}°C</Card.Text>
        <Card.Text>Humidity: {weather.main.humidity}%</Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default WeatherCard;
```

The App.js file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Container, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import WeatherCard from './WeatherCard';

const App = () => {
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/weather?city=${city}`
      );
      setWeatherData(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>Weather Forecast</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Enter City</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            value={city}
            onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button type="submit">Get Weather</Button>
      </Form>
      {weatherData && <WeatherCard weather={weatherData} />}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The WeatherController.js file:

```
// weatherController.js
const axios = require('axios');

const apiKey = 'Here I got the API key from openweathermap api';

exports.getWeatherByCity = async (req, res) => {
  const { city } = req.query;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`
    );
    res.json(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Unable to fetch weather data' });
  }
};
```

I've tried to check if MongoDB is running or not after trying net start MongoDB - tired first on VS code terminal and getting: System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied - by accessing windows terminal, and running net start MongoDB resulting:The requested service has already been started.

What could be possible issues to fix this?
Please help.

Comment: Chane the `const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost/weather_app';` to const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/weather_app'; Also check if you have any auth than pass it as 

mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/weather_ap

Comment: @HiteshP I have done so, but still had same error, so aside from adding 27017, I switched out localhost with the actual IP of it and it worked, thanks.